# SQL Server Stored Procedure Returns All Result properly for otherdays except the Starting day

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I am facing a problem while trying to get the data from my database & displaying it in gridview. in front-end i have a page where i will search the report for a particular day. My code is working properly for all days except the 1st day. for the 1st day it is not displaying any values.1st day means, suppose i entered opening balance entry on 01/06/2014 in opening balance table . & in search page i want to see the report for 22/06/2014 then it is working fine. but if i want to see the report of 01/06/2014 it is not showing any result.

From this stored procedure i am getting the report data which i have written :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetDatailsForDailyReport] 
   @vDate VARCHAR(50)
AS
--DECLARE @vPrevDate VARCHAR(50)
BEGIN
--SET @vPrevDate=(SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DD, 0, CONVERT(datetime,'19/06/2014',103)), -1),103)) 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
 select PrevOpening.SchoolID,
 SCHOOLDETAILS.SchoolName,
 SCHOOLDETAILS.SchoolCode,
 SCHOOLDETAILS.SansadNo,
 SCHOOLDETAILS.Circle,
 isnull(NOOFSTUDENTS.TotalNoOfStudents,0) AS NoOfStudents, 
 isnull(PrevOpening.RecRice,0)-isnull(PrevConsumption.ConRice,0) OpeningRice,
 isnull(RECEIVING.CurRecRice,0) RecvRice,
  isnull(CONSUMPTION.CurConRice,0) ConRice,
 (((isnull(PrevOpening.RecRice,0)-isnull(PrevConsumption.ConRice,0))+ isnull(RECEIVING.CurRecRice,0))- isnull(CONSUMPTION.CurConRice,0)) ClosingRice,
 isnull(PrevOpening.RecAmount,0)-isnull(PrevConsumption.ConAmount,0) OpeningAmount,
 isnull(RECEIVING.CurRecAmount,0) RecvAmount,
  isnull(CONSUMPTION.CurConAmount,0) ConAmount,
 (((isnull(PrevOpening.RecAmount,0)-isnull(PrevConsumption.ConAmount,0))+ isnull(RECEIVING.CurRecAmount,0))- isnull(CONSUMPTION.CurConAmount,0)) ClosingAmount
 FROM
     (
         SELECT
                SchoolID,
                ISNULL (SUM(isnull(Rice,0)),0) AS RecRice,
                ISNULL (SUM(isnull(Amount,0)),0) AS RecAmount
        FROM tblOpeningBalance
        WHERE Date<CONVERT(datetime,@vDate,103) Group BY SchoolID   
       ) PrevOpening
        LEFT JOIN
        (
        SELECT SchoolID,
                ISNULL (SUM(isnull(Rice,0)),0) AS ConRice,
                ISNULL (SUM(isnull(Amount,0)),0) AS ConAmount
                --SUM(NoOfStudent) AS PrevTotalNoOfStudents
        FROM tblDailyMidDayDetails
        WHERE Date<CONVERT(datetime,@vDate,103) Group BY SchoolID
        ) PrevConsumption
         ON  PrevOpening.SchoolID=PrevConsumption.SchoolID
        LEFT JOIN
        (
        SELECT 
        SchoolID,
        ISNULL (SUM(isnull(Rice,0)),0) AS CurRecRice,
        ISNULL (SUM(isnull(Amount,0)),0)AS CurRecAmount
        FROM tblOpeningBalance 
        WHERE 
        Date=CONVERT(datetime,@vDate,103) GROUP BY SchoolID
        ) RECEIVING 
        ON  PrevOpening.SchoolID=RECEIVING.SchoolID
        LEFT JOIN
        (
        SELECT 
        SchoolID,
        ISNULL (SUM(isnull(Rice,0)),0) AS CurConRice,
        ISNULL (SUM(isnull(Amount,0)),0) AS CurConAmount
        --ISNULL (SUM(isnull(NoOfStudent,0)),0) AS TotalNoOfStudents
        FROM tblDailyMidDayDetails
        WHERE
        Date=CONVERT(datetime,@vDate,103) GROUP BY SchoolID
        ) CONSUMPTION 
        ON PrevOpening.SchoolID=CONSUMPTION.SchoolID
        LEFT JOIN
        (
        SELECT
        SchoolID,
        SchoolName,
        SchoolCode,
        SansadNo,
        Circle
        FROM
        tblSchoolDetails
        ) SCHOOLDETAILS
        ON PrevOpening.SchoolID=SCHOOLDETAILS.SchoolID
        LEFT JOIN
        (
        SELECT
        SchoolID,
        SUM(NoOfStudent) AS TotalNoOfStudents 
        FROM
        tblDailyMidDayDetails
        WHERE
        Date=CONVERT(datetime,@vDate,103) GROUP BY SchoolID 
        ) NOOFSTUDENTS
        ON PrevOpening.SchoolID=NOOFSTUDENTS.SchoolID
END
```

Now the stored procedure for inserting in `OpeningBalance` table is :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_InsertOpeningBalance]
(
@vOpeningBalanceID INT
,@vDate NVARCHAR(10)
,@vSchoolID INT
,@vRice NVARCHAR(30)
,@vAmount NVARCHAR(30)
,@ReturnVal INT OUTPUT
)
    AS
    DECLARE @DupCount INT
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF (@vOpeningBalanceID=0)
BEGIN
SET @DupCount=(SELECT COUNT(SchoolID) FROM [dbo].[tblOpeningBalance] WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Date,103)=CONVERT (VARCHAR(10),@vDate,103) AND SchoolID=@vSchoolID)
IF (@DupCount>0)
BEGIN
SET @ReturnVal=-70
END
ELSE
BEGIN 
            INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblOpeningBalance]
                (
                     Date
                    ,SchoolID
                    ,Rice
                    ,Amount 
                )
                VALUES
                (
                     CONVERT(datetime, @vDate, 103)
                     ,@vSchoolID
                     ,CONVERT(float,@vRice)
                     ,CONVERT(float,@vAmount)
                )

            SET @ReturnVal=1
END
        END
ELSE
        BEGIN
            UPDATE [dbo].[tblOpeningBalance]
                SET  
                Date= CONVERT(datetime, @vDate, 103)
                ,SchoolID=@vSchoolID
                ,Rice=CONVERT(float,@vRice)
                ,Amount=CONVERT(float,@vAmount)
                WHERE OpeningBalanceID=@vOpeningBalanceID   

            SET @ReturnVal=2
        END  
END
```

This is the stored procedure for insertion of daily midday meal details for daily consumption in midday meal table.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_InsertDailyMidDayDetails]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
        (
             @vSchoolID INT
            ,@vDate NVARCHAR(20)
            ,@vNoOfStudent INT
            ,@vRice NVARCHAR(30)
            ,@vAmount NVARCHAR(30)
            ,@vVisitTypeID INT

            ,@ReturnVal INT OUTPUT
        )
AS
    DECLARE @i_count INT
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN
         SET @i_count=(SELECT COUNT(ID) 
                                   FROM tblDailyMidDayDetails 
                                   WHERE ltrim(rtrim(Date))=ltrim(rtrim(@vDate)) );

                    IF (@i_count  >0) 
                        BEGIN
                                SET @ReturnVal = -70;      
                        END
                    ELSE
                        BEGIN

                            INSERT INTO tblDailyMidDayDetails
                                (
                                    SchoolID
                                    ,Date
                                    ,NoOfStudent
                                    ,Rice
                                    ,Amount
                                    ,VisitTypeID
                                )
                                VALUES
                                (
                                    @vSchoolID
                                    ,CONVERT(DATETIME,@vDate,103)
                                    ,@vNoOfStudent
                                    ,CONVERT(float,@vRice)
                                    ,CONVERT(FLOAT,@vAmount)
                                    ,@vVisitTypeID
                                )

                                SET @ReturnVal=1
                        END
    END
END
```

Can anyone guide me what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the Correction which i have done it by myself.  Now i am getting perfect result.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetDatailsForDailyReport] 
    @vDate VARCHAR(50)

    AS
    --DECLARE @vPrevDate VARCHAR(50)
    BEGIN
    --SET @vPrevDate=(SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DD, 0, CONVERT(datetime,'19/06/2014',103)), -1),103)) 
        SET NOCOUNT ON;


        -- Insert statements for procedure here
     select PrevOpening.SchoolID,
     SCHOOLDETAILS.SchoolName,
     SCHOOLDETAILS.SchoolCode,
     SCHOOLDETAILS.SansadNo,
     SCHOOLDETAILS.Circle,
     isnull(NOOFSTUDENTS.TotalNoOfStudents,0) AS NoOfStudents, 
     isnull(PrevOpening.RecRice,0)-isnull(PrevConsumption.ConRice,0)+ isnull(RECEIVING.CurRecRice,0) OpeningRice,
     isnull(RECEIVING.CurRecRice,0) RecvRice,
      isnull(CONSUMPTION.CurConRice,0) ConRice,
     (((isnull(PrevOpening.RecRice,0)-isnull(PrevConsumption.ConRice,0))+ isnull(RECEIVING.CurRecRice,0))- isnull(CONSUMPTION.CurConRice,0)) ClosingRice,
     isnull(PrevOpening.RecAmount,0)-isnull(PrevConsumption.ConAmount,0)+ isnull(RECEIVING.CurRecAmount,0) OpeningAmount,
     isnull(RECEIVING.CurRecAmount,0) RecvAmount,
      isnull(CONSUMPTION.CurConAmount,0) ConAmount,
     (((isnull(PrevOpening.RecAmount,0)-isnull(PrevConsumption.ConAmount,0))+ isnull(RECEIVING.CurRecAmount,0))- isnull(CONSUMPTION.CurConAmount,0)) ClosingAmount
     FROM
            (
            SELECT
            SchoolID,
            SchoolName,
            SchoolCode,
            SansadNo,
            Circle
            FROM
            tblSchoolDetails

            WHERE IsApproved=1
            ) SCHOOLDETAILS
            LEFT JOIN
              (
             SELECT
                    SchoolID,
                    ISNULL (SUM(isnull(Rice,0)),0) AS RecRice,
                    ISNULL (SUM(isnull(Amount,0)),0) AS RecAmount
            FROM tblOpeningBalance
            WHERE Date<CONVERT(datetime,@vDate,103) Group BY SchoolID   
           ) PrevOpening
           ON   SCHOOLDETAILS.SchoolID=PrevOpening.SchoolID
           LEFT JOIN

            (
            SELECT SchoolID,
                    ISNULL (SUM(isnull(Rice,0)),0) AS ConRice,
                    ISNULL (SUM(isnull(Amount,0)),0) AS ConAmount
                    --SUM(NoOfStudent) AS PrevTotalNoOfStudents
            FROM tblDailyMidDayDetails
            WHERE Date<CONVERT(datetime,@vDate,103) Group BY SchoolID
            ) PrevConsumption
             ON  SCHOOLDETAILS.SchoolID=PrevConsumption.SchoolID
             LEFT JOIN
         (
            SELECT 
            SchoolID,
            ISNULL (SUM(isnull(Rice,0)),0) AS CurRecRice,
            ISNULL (SUM(isnull(Amount,0)),0)AS CurRecAmount
            FROM tblOpeningBalance 
            WHERE 
            Date=CONVERT(datetime,@vDate,103) GROUP BY SchoolID
            ) RECEIVING 
            ON SCHOOLDETAILS.SchoolID=RECEIVING.SchoolID
            LEFT JOIN


            (
            SELECT 
            SchoolID,
            ISNULL (SUM(isnull(Rice,0)),0) AS CurConRice,
            ISNULL (SUM(isnull(Amount,0)),0) AS CurConAmount
            --ISNULL (SUM(isnull(NoOfStudent,0)),0) AS TotalNoOfStudents
            FROM tblDailyMidDayDetails
            WHERE
            Date=CONVERT(datetime,@vDate,103) GROUP BY SchoolID
            ) CONSUMPTION 
            ON  SCHOOLDETAILS.SchoolID=CONSUMPTION.SchoolID

                LEFT JOIN
            (
            SELECT
            SchoolID,
            SUM(NoOfStudent) AS TotalNoOfStudents 
            FROM
            tblDailyMidDayDetails
            WHERE
            Date=CONVERT(datetime,@vDate,103) GROUP BY SchoolID 
            ) NOOFSTUDENTS
            ON SCHOOLDETAILS.SchoolID=NOOFSTUDENTS.SchoolID




END
```

Answer (score 2):

You have several different variable types for the date.

```
@vDate VARCHAR(50)
@vDate NVARCHAR(10)
@vDate NVARCHAR(20)
```

Why the difference?

Why not just store as

```
date
```

Comment: +1 yes - exactly - always use the **proper data type!**

Comment: because I am passing string from Front-End & converting it into datetime.

Comment: if you mean NVARCHAR & VARCHAR then i must say .. i have taken VARCHAR & my CO-WORKER took NVARCHAR.

Comment: Let the front end handle the conversion/application.  And let the database do what it does best; store data.